# How to get input data of PDF form submited as HTML format in servlet?

Tags: pdf, servlets

I have a PDF form which contains some fields as below
[PDF download link](http://cyclops49.sg1002.myweb.hinet.net/testPDF2.pdf)

input text field name as "name"
input checkbox field name as "language"
input radio button field name as "sex"
select combobox field name as "job"
submit button action as HTML format, and submit URL to http://local.test.com/servlet1

and servlet1 which has code as blow

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    for(Enumeration e = request.getParameterNames(); e.hasMoreElements();) {
        String paraName = (String) e.nextElement();
        String paramValue = URLDecoder.decode(new String(request.getParameter(paraName).getBytes("iso-8859-1")), "UTF-8");
        System.out.println(paraName + "=" + paramValue);
    }               
}
```

than I input some data in the PDF form and click submit, and I got System output as below

```
SystemOut     O sex=M
SystemOut     O input7=eric
SystemOut     O input34=zhTW
SystemOut     O job=1
```

the field of "sex"(radio button) and "job"(select combo) are OK, but why the field name of "name"(input text) and "language"(checkbox) are changed to "inputXX"?

And I try to use

```
request.getParameter("name")
```

and I just got null...

Is there any suggestion?
many thanks...

Comment: As you can see, name isn't defined in parameters you receive. Check the name of the field in the PDF form.

Comment: I'm very sure the field name is what I assigned, and I write javascript to getField("name").value, it' also alert "eric", but I don't know why the field name changed to "input7" after submit?

Comment: If you want more specific information, supply the PDF file.

Comment: I've added my sample PDF file link in the post

Answer (score 0):

I inspected your form, and I see the field with name "name" as well as submit buttons that post the data to an URL. One of those submit buttons limits the number of parameters sent to the server.

I didn't see any immediate error, but I suggest that you use the following Servlet to debug your application: http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=169

This servlet will show all the parameters as a query string in case of a GET request (but at first sight, the PDF is configured to POST the data); in case of a POST, it will display all the data that is sent. This way, you can figure out what goes wrong.

Keep us posted.

Answer (score 0):

When exporting the value of the text field `name` using the identifier `input7`, the PDF viewer just does what it is asked to do as the field dictionary of the name field contains an entry requesting the field value to be exported using the key `input7`. The same goes for some other fields, too.

In detail the field dictionary (object 106 0) contains the following entries:

```
/Ff 4194306
/F  4
/Type   /Annot
/Subtype    /Widget
/T  name
/AP Dictionary
/P  42 0 R
/MK Dictionary
/BS Dictionary
/FT /Tx
/Rect   [54.8909, 688.564, 161.891, 705.564]
/DA /Helv 0 Tf 0 g
/TM input7
```

Have a look at the last entry. The /TM key is defined as (cf. [ISO 32000-1:2008](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) section 12.7.3.1):

> text string *(Optional; PDF 1.3)* The mapping name that shall be used
>   when exporting interactive form field data from the document

If you do not want the field value to be exported with that `input7` key, remove that **/TM** entry from the field definition.

Comment: May I ask how to get the message as above (/Ff 4194306... /TM input7), anyone tools or something?

Comment: I'm using [RUPS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextrups/) and (in case of good old PDFs without object streams) text viewers.

Answer (score 0):

The PDF file was translated from HTML file by Acrobat X Pro, and I noticed some fileds such as "name"...

```
<input id="name" type='text'>
```

than I update HTML file

```
<input name="name" type='text'>
```

and translated to PDF again and submit, everything is OK now ~ :)